# How to improve a bunch of else-if conditions that evaluate a variable inside a range among known values?

Tags: c++, performance, if-statement, function-pointers

Is there any way to convert this code below into something more scalable? I've simplified it, but my real one has to check for several different values and it is asking for refactoring.

```
     if (x < 0) foo1();
else if (x < 3) foo2();
else if (x < 8) foo3();
else            foo4();
```

I've tried the following:

```
struct Ptr2foo {
    void (*foo_x)();
}

Ptr2foo ptr2foo_x[4] {
    foo1,
    foo2,
    foo3,
    foo4
}

ptr2foo_x[someMagicWithMy_X_AndMyKnownValues].foo_x();
```

Those values are known before compiling, and that amount of conditions inside a loop are killing performance.

Is this the best way to approach this issue? Any alternative solution with its explanation is highly appreciated

Comment: How many viable values of `x` are there? If you're in some kind of hot-loop, is `x` computed outside of the loop? Would it be possible to pre-compute an enumerator outside of the loop, then use a switch inside of it?

Comment: @walnut ```x``` varies along the execution

Comment: Read up on the switch-case concept. But I think the first piece of shown code is the best you can do.

Comment: @NicolBolas ```x``` goes from 0 to +inf, and it is calculated inside the loop. ```x``` represents the distance between two moving points. Inside that loop, I calculate the distance and call one function or another depending on that distance

Comment: Is there some kind of relationship between the different distances? I.e. if they are some kind of linear function `a*t +b` you can transform `x` to `(x-b)/a` and then use a switch on the corresponding value of `t`.

Comment: @Mateo: Then you're going to have to get really clever (which will require knowledge of the specific algorithm) or you're going to have to buy your performance elsewhere.

Comment: @n314159 that is exactly what im looking for when i wrote _someMagicWithMy_X_AndMyKnownValues_ and i have no clue at all on how to write a function rule for a piecewise one

Comment: @Mateo You could ask another question for your specific function maybe there is a way to simplify that. Furthermore even in the general case of finding the right interval there is way to be a bit faster, I am currently writing an answer for that. But it will never be as fast as hand-tailored magic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the general case that you have some intervals `[a1, a2), [a2, a3), ..., [an, infty)` and want to find the interval in which `x` lies, you can do it with worst-case `log n` comparisons (vs. your if-else-chain that has worst-case `n` comparisons). You do that by doing binary search on the intervals. So you will check first if `x` is smaller than `a(n/2)` and then further check the smaller intervalls in the `if`-case and the bigger in the `else`-case. For your example from above, transform

```cpp
     if (x < 0) foo1();
else if (x < 3) foo2();
else if (x < 8) foo3();
else            foo4();
```

which has 4 comparisons on it longest path and 1 on its shortest to

```cpp
if( x < 3 ) {
  if( x < 0 ) foo1();
  else        foo2();
} else {
  if( x < 8 ) foo3();
  else        foo4();
}
```

This has 2 comparisons on all its paths.

Note that less comparisons in the worst case are not necessarily faster. It is faster if `x` is roughly equally distributed. If `x` is negative in 90% of the cases, your first version will be faster since it mostly will only use one comparison, while my version uses always 2.

That is why you should also think about what is the hot-path (i.e. most frequent path) through this code is. If maybe `x` is at least 8 in most cases, you should definitely check it first and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `interval_map`. There is a sample implementation of it [here](https://github.com/maranp/intervalmap/blob/master/interval_map.cpp)
Simply, it holds reference of anything in set range.
You need to fill the edge cases for your case like:

```
m_map.insert(std::make_pair(0, foo1));
m_map.insert(std::make_pair(3, foo2));
m_map.insert(std::make_pair(8, foo3));
```

then you can simply get the function you want with `m_map[1]`. this will return the first function in the map.

*Note: i give the link as a sample. Implementation may be problematic. You better test it before using.*

Comment: While I like this idea in general, one should be really careful with this. Even when the implementation is really good and you only do one lookup in the hot-path, this can be really slow due to a) overhead (I hope the count of if-statements is still in a range where overhead is much more important than asymptotic runtime) and b) the compiler being less able to optimize this since it is much more complicated logic.

Comment: I do like this approach for a generic problem (tricky but useful implementation) but  in this case a map will kill performance as all the data is linearly stored. I appreciate the answer  anyway

Comment: @Mateo: you might still have a "flat map" (`std::vector<std::pair<int, void(*)()>>`).